# Logic behind nearest neighbor interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, nearest-neighbor, linear-interpolation

I have an assignent where i need to recreate the nearest neighbor interpolation function from scratch in python.
I just started the language a few days ago so i'm trying to write every little steps to achieve that.

This is my first try to solve it :)
The reasoning behind it is **(for a given image and a scale of 0.5 for example)** to scale the positions X and Y of the original image to X' and Y' like this:

Shape of the given image : 10x10. 
I want to scale it to 5x5 **(this is a downscaling)**

**X and Y positions before scaling**

X=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

**X and Y positions after scaling**

X'=[0,2.25,4.5,6.75,9]
Y'=[0,2.25,4.5,6.75,9]

**rounded**

X'=[0,2,5,7,9]
Y'=[0,2,5,7,9]

Then i look up the pixels from the original image using those positions

I dont know if this make sense or i'm missing something

**My code**
(the way i named my variables is not so great)

```
def interpolation_nn(image, scale):

    # saving the type of the image
    dtype = image.dtype

    #Adding padding to the image
    img_p = np.pad(image.astype(np.float32), 1)

    # Calculation of the size of the original image and of the interpolated image
    #Original img
    height,width = image.shape 

    #interpolated image
    Scaled_width = (width * scale)
    Scaled_height = (height * scale)

    # Calculation of pixel coordinates in the interpolated image
    Scaled_X_coordinates=np.linspace(0.0, width, num=Scaled_width)
    Scaled_Y_coordinates=np.linspace(0.0, height, num=Scaled_height)

    #rounding my positions
    Scaled_X_coordinates=np.around(Scaled_X_coordinates)
    Scaled_Y_coordinates=np.around(Scaled_Y_coordinates)

    #edited
    finalMatrix= np.zeros(shape=(np.around(Scaled_height).astype(int) ,np.around(Scaled_width).astype(int)))
    pixels=[]

    #Here, i store every pixels from the original image using the scaled coordinates
    #into an array of pixels
    for Line in Scaled_Y_coordinates.astype(int)  :
        for Column in Scaled_X_coordinates.astype(int):
            pixel = img_p[Line,Column]
            pixels.append(pixel)

    #Here i reconstruct the scaled image using the array of pixels from above
    Pixel_counter=0
    for i in range(np.around(Scaled_height).astype(int)):
        for j in range(np.around(Scaled_width).astype(int)):
            finalMatrix[i][j]=pixels[Pixel_counter]
            Pixel_counter=Pixel_counter+1

    #returning a new matrix with the same type as the given img
    return finalMatrix.astype(dtype)
```

I have no idea how to look up into the pixels of the original image to recreate the new one having the new scaled positions. If something is unclear, please ask:)

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right in your calculations, then the missing piece is just as simple as:

```
for a in X_corresponding :
    column = [image[a,b] for b in Y_corresponding]
    finalMatrix.append( column )
```

---

Here's ready to use solution:

```
def nn_interpolate(A, new_size):
    """Vectorized Nearest Neighbor Interpolation"""

    old_size = A.shape
    row_ratio, col_ratio = np.array(new_size)/np.array(old_size)

    # row wise interpolation 
    row_idx = (np.ceil(range(1, 1 + int(old_size[0]*row_ratio))/row_ratio) - 1).astype(int)

    # column wise interpolation
    col_idx = (np.ceil(range(1, 1 + int(old_size[1]*col_ratio))/col_ratio) - 1).astype(int)

    final_matrix = A[:, row_idx][col_idx, :]

return final_matrix
```

or if you want more details, here's URL where I got it from:
https://gist.github.com/KeremTurgutlu/68feb119c9dd148285be2e247267a203

Comment: Hello :) The ouput of np.around() is of type float. I can't use floats for indexing arrays :/ `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: i tried to add `.astype(int)` but there is an out of bounds error

Comment: And i would not be able to return finalMatrix because `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: @Hazel it seems like your calculation of indices is somehow flawed. Please, either debug it yourself or use the ready-to-use solution I've posted in the answer.

Comment: if i try `X=nn_interpolate(img,0.5)
plt.imshow(X)
plt.show()` on the function it does not work

Comment: i think i need to do some sort of conversion from an image to a readable matrix in order for your function to work and i have no idea how to acheive that

Comment: @Hazel `new_size` supposed to be a `tuple()`, like `(640, 480)`, not a ratio.

Comment: I tried `X=nn_interpolate(img,(100,150))
plt.imshow(X)
plt.show()` I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (540,) (100,)`, my img had  widght:466
 height:540